# Swagger 2 Relative path references are not getting resolved

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

While using java Swagger2 parser, the relative references are not getting resolved, if the references are in some other folder.

Is there a way to define what should be the root path from where the references should be resolved.

Eg. If a file located in https://example.com/content/test/api/swagger/test.yaml
has a reference,
$ref: '../some-other-folder/message.yaml#/definitions/MessageArray'

and the file is located  in https://example.com/content/test/api/some-other-folder/message.yaml

the parser is not  able to resolve the relative path and throws the error.

Is there a way to resolve a relative path with a given base path, eg user could provide an option to always resolve the relative paths using https://example.com/content/test/api/ and the content of relative path is appended to the give url, thus forming the location https://example.com/content/test/api/some-other-folder/message.yaml ?

This works in OpenAPIV3Parser.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use the latest 1.x version of `swagger-parser` (1.0.46)?

Comment: Hi, Yes. i am using the latest version.

Comment: Looks like a bug, maybe this one https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/713